# Hide/show div based on search input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have worked out some javascript to use my search bar in order to filter/hide things that don't match the search input. I've got it working about 95% I would say but I have one problem to fix.

So my page displays furniture groups and their containing pieces of furniture. The group name/number and description exists as a heading div and below that there is a table created with the actual pieces of furniture. My current javascript works as long as I'm typing 'sofa' or 'chair' which would be in the table row. However, If I type the name of a furniture group, it just shows the name/number/description and images, but hides the table. The group names/descriptions are in this block:

```
@foreach ($orderFormData->pgroups as $pgroup)
<div class="group-container">
        <h3 style="font-size: 26px; padding: 10px 0;">{{ $pgroup->group_name 
}} - {{ $pgroup->group_code }}</h3>
        <p class="uk-text-muted" style="font-size: 20px;" >{!! 
html_entity_decode($pgroup->group_desc) !!}</p>
```

So, I need to try and slightly refactor this to add the functionality so that if my input matches the group name or description, it still shows the whole table for that div.

An idea I had was to add something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if($('.group-container').children('tr:visible').length == 0) {
$('.group-container').hide();
} else {
$('.group-container').show();
}
</script>
```

Under my first line of html below, right under the foreach loop. But I don't know if that would be the right idea or how to use that exactly the way it should.

HTML:

```
@foreach ($orderFormData->pgroups as $pgroup)
<div class="group-container">
        <h3 style="font-size: 26px; padding: 10px 0;">{{ $pgroup->group_name }} - {{ $pgroup->group_code }}</h3>
        <p class="uk-text-muted" style="font-size: 20px;" >{!! html_entity_decode($pgroup->group_desc) !!}</p> <!--Group Description-->

        <div class="uk-grid">
            <div class="uk-width-2-10">
                <ul style="margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style-type: none; float: left; width: 100%;">
                    @foreach ($pgroup->image_names as $image_name)
                    <li><a href="/imagelib/Bigthumbs/{{ substr($image_name, 0, strpos($image_name, ',')) }}" target=_blank><img src="/imagelib/Bigthumbs/{{ substr($image_name, 0, strpos($image_name, ',')) }}" style="width: 100%; height: auto;" /></a><span class="uk-text-center" style="padding: 0 0 5px;">{{ substr($image_name, strpos( $image_name, ',') + 1)  }}</span></li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="uk-width-8-10">
                <table id="userTbl" class="uk-table" style="width: 100%; min-width: 768px;">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 10%; font-size: 20px;">Frame</th>
                        <th style="width: 20%; font-size: 20px;">Description</th>
                        <th style="width: 15%; font-size: 20px;">Cover/Color</th>
                        <th style="width: 15%; font-size: 20px;">Cover/Color</th>
                        <th style="width: 20%; font-size: 20px;">Quantity</th>
                        <th style="width: 15%; font-size: 20px; text-align: center;"><b>Price</b></th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>

                    @foreach ($pgroup->pskus as $psku)
                    <?php $tempdata['sku-' . $i] = $psku ?>
                    <tr class="@if (isset($psku->quantity) && $psku->quantity > 0) {{ highlight }} @endif">
                        <td style="font-weight: 500; line-height: 30px; font-size: 14px;">{{ $psku->frame_fmt }}</td>
                        <td style="font-weight: 500; line-height: 30px; font-size: 14px;">{!! html_entity_decode($psku->frame_desc) !!}</td>
                        <td style="font-weight: 500; line-height: 30px; font-size: 14px;">{{ $psku->cover1_code }}/{{ $psku->color1_code }} {{ $psku->color1_desc }}</td>
                        <td style="font-weight: 500; line-height: 30px; font-size: 14px;">{{ $psku->cover2_code }}/{{ $psku->color2_code }} {{ $psku->color2_desc }}</td>
                        <td style="font-weight: 700; line-height: 30px; font-size: 14px;">
                            <span style="text-align: center; display: block; width: 100%;">${{ $psku->price }}</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php $i++; ?>
                    @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

        </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

JS:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#srch-term").keyup(function(){

    // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
    var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;

    // Loop through the main container as well as the table body and row that contains the match
    $(".group-container, tbody tr").each(function(){

        // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
        if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
            $(this).fadeOut();

        // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
        } else {
            $(this).show();
            count++;
        }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could search the groups first and if the name/description matches, show the whole group and all it's rows. Otherwise do the usual procedure.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#srch-term").keyup(function(){

    // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
    var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;
    var search_regex = new RegExp(filter, "i")

    // Loop through the main container as well as the table body and row that contains the match
    $(".group-container").each(function(){
        //check if filter matches the group name or description
        var group_name = $(this).children('h3').text()
        var group_description = $(this).children('.uk-text-muted').text()

        if(group_name.search(search_regex)>=0 || group_description.search(search_regex)>=0){ // filter matches
            $(this).show() // show group
            $(this).find("tbody tr").show() // and all children
            return // skip tr filtering
        }

        var no_matches = true

        $(this).find("tbody tr").each(function(){

            // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
            if ($(this).text().search(search_regex) < 0) {
                $(this).fadeOut();

            // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
            } else {
                $(this).show();
                count++;
                no_matches = false
            }
        });

        if(no_matches){ // if no tr matched the search either, hide whole group
            $(this).fadeOut();
        }

    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for the timely response and a Perfectly working solution! I hadn't thought of that procedure at all. If I had a <tr> class called "Available" would I be able to omit that from the match completely in this? LIke, check every row except this class?

Comment: Since you combine all the tr contents into one string with `text()` you'd need some small refactoring. A quick hack would be to simply remove the word "Available" from the string like this: `if ($(this).text().replace('Available','').search(search_regex) < 0)` Let me know if you'd like a more solid solution.